# How to serve a Ionic v4 custom project

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to create and serve a Ionic v4 app without Angular. I want to use the Ionic v4 UI components in HTML with Vanilla JavaScript.

**My first plan:**

I try to use the Ionic CLI 4.12.0. When I do

```
ionic start --list
```

then I get

```
name     | project type  | description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
blank    | angular       | A blank starter project
sidemenu | angular       | A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
tabs     | angular       | A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
tabs     | ionic-angular | A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
blank    | ionic-angular | A blank starter project
sidemenu | ionic-angular | A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
super    | ionic-angular | A starting project complete with pre-built pages, providers and best practices for Ionic development.
tutorial | ionic-angular | A tutorial based project that goes along with the Ionic documentation
aws      | ionic-angular | AWS Mobile Hub Starter
tabs     | ionic1        | A starting project for Ionic using a simple tabbed interface
blank    | ionic1        | A blank starter project for Ionic
sidemenu | ionic1        | A starting project for Ionic using a side menu with navigation in the content area
maps     | ionic1        | An Ionic starter project using Google Maps and a side menu
```

Even it is not offered, I tried it anyway to create a custom project with:

```
ionic start blank-app blank --type=custom
```

then I get an error:

```
[ERROR] custom is not a valid project type.
```

There seems to be no way with the Ionic CLI.

**My second plan:**

I initialize a new node project

```
npm init
```

and install Ionic

```
npm i @ionic/core
```

and initialize this existing projects with Ionic CLI

```
ionic init blank-app --type=custom
```

Then I add some Ionic compoments into index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src='node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/ionic.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@ionic/core/css/core.css">
    <title>my-app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ion-app>
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar color="primary">
                <ion-title>header-title</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col>
                        <ion-button id="btn-add">
                            <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>Add
                        </ion-button>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-app>
    <script src="src/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the src/app.js I can implement the business logic.

```
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#btn-add');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   alert('click add button');
});
```

That's everything good.

Now I can install a package like serve

```
npm install serve --save-dev
```

for development purpose and with a script in the package.json I can start it with a

```
npm start
```

Yes, thats works.

**But here is my question. What I have todo, to serve my project with the Ionic CLI?**

```
ionic serve -c
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think at the moment u can use custom project just with Ionic1.

But if you want to use components of Ionic 4

after creating  app with:

> ionic start test-app blank --type=ionic1

go to your_app/www/index.html and integrate the Ionic CDN in your index.html, now u can use the components of Ionic 4 if u want or use just vanilla javascript with HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Card</title>
  <!-- Import the Ionic CSS -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Import Ionic -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic.js"></script>
<!-- Optional, import the Ionic icons -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@latest/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-header translucent>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Card</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>,
    <ion-content fullscreen>
      <ion-card>
        <img src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/card/madison.jpg" />
        <div id="test"></div>
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-subtitle>Destination</ion-card-subtitle>
          <ion-card-title>Madison, WI</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
          Founded in 1829 on an isthmus between Lake Monona and Lake Mendota, Madison was named the capital of the Wisconsin Territory in 1836.
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-app>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Your Javascript
    document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = "<h2>Hello World</h2>"
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and now u can serve your javascript app using :

> ionic serve

I hope this will help you